# hide after show onclick with jquery

Tags: jquery

Thanks for reading.

I have a comment list. and users click reply link a form comes out. Then with jquery i change reply link with cancel. when you click cancel it hides the form but when you click again it shows and hides.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zv3uy/10/ this is the action with my code.

is this approach right? I'm trying to learn.

here are the codes.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    $('.reply-comment').on('click', function(e){
        var CommentID = $(this).attr('id');
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).next('.reply-form').show(function(){
            $('#'+CommentID).html('<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="reply-comment-'+CommentID+'"> Cancel </a>');

            $('.reply-comment').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                $(this).next('.reply-form').hide(function(){
                    $('#'+CommentID).html('<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="reply-comment-'+CommentID+'"> Reply </a>');
                });
            });

        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div>comments text etc etc...</div>
<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="2"> Reply </a>
<div class="reply-form well">
    <form name="reply-form" id="reply-form" method="POST">
        <textarea name="Comment" rows="6" class="span10"></textarea> <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary replycommentsubmitbutton" value="Reply" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Problems galore ! When you click on reply twice , it collapses the full window .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With every click you're binding another click event to the link.

I would do it like that:

```
$(function () {
    $('.reply-comment').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).next('.reply-form');
        var CommentID = $(this).attr('id');

        if ($form.is(':visible')) {
            // hide it
            $form.hide(function () {
                $('#' + CommentID).html('<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="reply-comment-' + CommentID + '"> Reply </a>');
            });
        } else {
            // show it
            $form.show(function () {
                $('#' + CommentID).html('<a href="" class="reply-comment" id="reply-comment-' + CommentID + '"> Cancel </a>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This way you only have one `click` and its more tidy (tidier?).

http://jsfiddle.net/Zv3uy/12/

Comment: Hi thanks. This code is working just fine. I was thinking to use 'if' but then I saw this reply. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933124/jquery-show-hide-comment-reply?rq=1 . he offers him to use toggle(). what do you think?

Comment: @ErdemEce toggle() would work as well, but if you're doing additional stuff when toggling (like in your case changing the link text), then you'd need an if anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should unbind old event before binding new one

```
$('.reply-comment').off('click').on('click', function(e){
```